# FlowNavigationNextEvent does not trigger

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, winter23

I am facing an interesting issue on a second generation managed package on **Winter 23**. In the lightning web component when a certain condition is not met, component fires a `FlowNavigationNextEvent` to automatically move to the next screen. This behaviour is working on **Summer 22** (*and was working well before that as well*) however in Winter23 sandbox we found that it stopped working.

Has anyone faced a similar issue on a lightning web component with flow navigation?

Code and the flow is pretty standard and has not changed.

**Additional information**

I can verify that event is dispatched from the Chrome developer tools.

I created 2 scratch orgs, one with Summer 22 and the other one with Winter 23 if there are two screens with LWC using Flow Next, *second screen navigation does not work for Winter 23 while it is working for Summer 22.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple reports of Flow screen navigation issues with LWC, Lightning Components in Winter'23 for which the product team has already filed below bugs and is actively working on them.

The issue you are seeing seems related to
**#W-11718377**: FlowNavigationNextEvent does not trigger in Winter 23

Details of other reported issues:

**#W-11719654**: If LWC are using FlowAttributeChangeEvent and FlowNavigationNextEvent together in a method while navigating to the next screen, System does not update the value of the variables which is expected from FlowAttributeChangeEvent.This is working fine in 238 Orgs

**#W-11697821** : Fields Feature In Screen Element Of Screen Flow With Conditional Visibility Doesn't Work In Winter 23' Release
KI Link: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000000zP66QAE

I will update this thread as I have more inputs on the KI/ ETA

Comment: Thanks @Swetha !